# What is the difference between gdal and python-gdal

Tags: apt, python

I am building a [dockerfile](https://github.com/rutgerhofste/gisDocker/blob/develop/Dockerfile) to work with geospatial data. I want to install the GDAL library and make it available to my anaconda python environment. There seem to be different ways to install gdal on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. Where can I find the difference between `apt-get install python-gdal -y` and `apt-get install gdal-bin -y`?

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/xenial/+source/gdal

Comment: python-gdal : The GDAL Python bindings https://pypi.python.org/pypi/GDAL ... libgdal : Geospatial Data Abstraction Library https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libgdal&searchon=names ... `libgdal(-dev)` is required for python-gdal .

Comment: There is no package named "gdal", so nothing to compare.